# CTRL-UP hex sequence

Tags: keyboard, hex

What is the HEX sequence for `CRTL-UP` key-press?
For example for `UP` - '0x1b, 0x5b, 0x41'.

Comment: Depends. What's your platform and context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple Python 3 script to find out the answer:

```
while True:
    print(" ".join("{:x}".format(ord(x)) for x in input()))
```

I had to turn off the standard "Mission control" shortcut for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> keystroke, but after doing that I get the following in iTerm2:

```
$ python3 test.py
^[[A
1b 5b 41
^[[1;5A
1b 5b 31 3b 35 41
```

The first two lines represent an <kbd>Up</kbd> keypress, while the second two lines represent a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>. You can use this same program to find out the character sequences for any other keystrokes.